# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Cannot Connect Remotely (Error 1326)

Tags: windows-7, remote, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008-r2

For some reason, now I cannot connect to my SQL Server 2008 server remotely.  I can login locally, but I get Error 1326 that I cannot connect to the server.  SQL Browser is running, firewall ports were opened (I used the script given in Microsoft support link and verified on the server), TCP/IP, named pipes, and shared memory are enabled.

Any idea why I still cannot access it?  I'm trying to connect from my laptop over a workstation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default, SQL Server will only allow the local connections. You'll have to run the Surface Area Configurator tool to open it up to allow the remote connections as well.

[edited later]

I stand corrected. SAC is gone with SQl Server 2008.

> Beginning in SQL Server 2008, the
>   Surface Area Configuration tool has
>   been removed. The features of the
>   Surface Area Configuration tool that
>   control SQL Server behavior have been
>   replaced and greatly enhanced in the
>   Policy-Based Management feature. [...]
>
> The connectivity management features
>   of the Surface Area Configuration tool
>   are available by using the
>   Configuration Manager tool. For more
>   information about this tool, see [SQL
>   Server Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx).

More details at the [SQL Server Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx) page in MSDN.

Comment: OK, in 2008 R2 there isn't any surface area configuration tool...

Comment: Did that resolve the issue?

Comment: No it didn't, strangely enough.  It used to be the fix many a time, but this time it appears to be something else... but I can't figure out what: remote connections are on and 1433 is enabled...

Answer (score 0):

Check the (Windows) firewall settings (and the SQL server settings) - by default windows does not allow SQL server to be remotely accessed.

Comment: 1433 is enabled in windows firewall...

Comment: @BrianMains: In both Inbound _and_ Outbound Rules?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I had to go into SQL Server Configuration Manager and start Sql Server Browser service. It was not running, and once I got that to run, I was able to connect over the network.

Also, enable TCP/IP protocol for SQL Server 2008 Express to accept remote connection under Network Protocol and Native Client settings in Configuration Manager.